# What is the purpose of converting all images users upload to the same filetype?

Tags: image, upload, storage, jpeg, file-type

I've noticed that many website change all their user-uploaded images to .jpg or .png format.
I am wondering what are the pros and cons of converting images to the same format.

Possible points of consideration are:

Security (I heard it is possible to put malicious code in images of certain filetypes)

Storage

Image quality

Scalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, after a user uploads a photo to a web application, some processing will be done to the image. For example, if a user uploads an avatar image, it will be cropped so that it is square, and resized so that all avatar images are the same size. Sometimes, we may want multiple resolutions of the same image for different display purposes (avatar icon vs. profile page). [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) is often the tool of choice for performing image processing on the server.

Comment: Thanks. The tool isn't an issue with my code; it's done client-side before getting saved to an S3. Even with processing, the code isn't a factor in this decision; it's about the same effort for me to keep or change the filetype. I'm trying to figure out if it is personal preference to have consistent filetypes or if there is a reason.

Comment: Usually, the resulting filetype is a product of the processing done to the image. If you wanted to shave a few extra bytes off of images, you might set compression levels and save to a specific format. If you are considering changing all the existing assets to have the same file format, it probably isn't worth your time.

Comment: What I got from this + research is that it's all about resources and preference. (Which is a helpful). No assets exist yet, it's a new application. I decided to make the component work both ways depending on the configuration. One thing I didn't consider when I created topic is .gif can be animated and .png files can have opacity. I don't want users posting animations in certain places, so in those cases, I'll make them all jpeg.